# How to tell image to stay centered - CSS

Tags: css, image, static, center, crop

I am building a website and I am using 2000px wide images. I want the images to be visible on wide screens (like mine - im using TV as monitor) but the smaller screens will only see the images size adequate to their size. (rest will be cropped). The problem is that the image must be centered no matter what size the viewport is. I have used `text-align:center;` to make the text responsive. I did read the similar topics but no matter what I do the image stays static and not centered. Please help.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            <img src="images/design/header.png">
        </div>

        <div class="nav-bar">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <a href="service.html">Service</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
        </div>

        <div class="side-bar">
            <h1>This is my side bar</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>This is my content</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <h1>This is my footer</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
max-width: 2000px;
margin: -8px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a responsive layout. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) provides the same by default.

Another way is by using @media tags. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp . Here, you will need to make a function like this: Get the screen size using mediacheck and then set up thresholds using @media.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css to make the image center. `max-width:100%` will fit the image if the container is smaller than the image width. the image width and height will be reduced to fit.

```
#wrapper > .header img
{
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
margin:0 auto; /* to make the image center of its container, if container is larger than image size */
}
```

**Update**

If you know the exact height of the image, then please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/75mmX/) fiddle. Resize [fullscreen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/75mmX/show/) to see the image cropping.

HTML:

```
<div class="position-img-outer">
    <div class="position-img-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" class="position-img" alt="img" style=" height: 300px; " />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.position-img-outer
{
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .position-img-outer .position-img-inner
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
}
.position-img-outer .position-img-inner .position-img
{
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one already, however it scales the image in both axis with the viewport. Thank You anyway!

Comment: Works Great! Is there any way to get rid of white gaps around the image? Thanks!

Comment: Well I cannot update the picture because of my reputation. The problem is that there is a 10px gap around the image from each side and I want it to be removed. Thanks

Comment: please inspect each elements in developer tools (F12) to see from which class the padding is being applied to the image.

Comment: I have just changed the margin to -8px and it works fine now. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the images, you can use the following:

```
#wrapper .header img{
    position:relative;
    width:2000px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1000px;
}
```

UPDATE:
To avoid a horizontal Scrollbar, you can set the container element to `width:100%` and `overflow:hidden`

```
#wrapper .header {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this on my laptop and it causes the horizontal scroll bar. Is there any way to avoid it ? Thanks